# Display the most recent Object from an Array (using mongodb and ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

```
 <% blogs.forEach(blog => { %>
      <h4><%= blog.title %></h4>
      <p><%= blog.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() %></p>
      <% }) %>
```

I have a database I can currently access on mongodb, and I'm using **express**, **ejs** and **node** to access and display them on my website

the code above is from a tutorial, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NrHkjlWVhM) and it will display every 'blog' in my 'blogs' database, but I only want to display one 'blog', the most recent 'blog'.

I am fairly new to Javascript, I have some HTML and CSS knowledge.

Comment: Give your route's controller code.

Comment: seem to have solved it: ``<h4"><%= latestBlog.title %></h4><p><%= latestBlog.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() %></p>`` and routes code:  ``app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const blogs = await Blog.find().sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home', blogs: blogs, latestBlog: blogs[0] })
})``